# Use the same graphic object OR Create a new one all the time in a FPS application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, graphics, bitmap

So I have an FPS application, Means that I am drawing a lot of "frames" per seconds.

Now basically I have a bitmap object, and it is my screen, it is like my buffer I am drawing a frame on this bitmap then I am drawing the buffer to the user screen, and I am doing this a lot of times in a second.
Because the DrawFrame function is used a lot of times, I need to make it as optimal as I can.

I have a graphic object that I am creating from the bitmap.

And the question is, do I need to create a **new** graphic object every time I draw a frame, Or do I need to make a public graphic object that will be used in the draw function.

This is the two options I have:

```
Public Class FpsEngine 'Exmaple Object
    Private Buffer As Bitmap
    Public Sub New()
        'initialize the object
    End Sub
    Public Sub DrawFrame() 'This fucntion will be called a lot of times and must be optimal
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Buffer)
            'Draw the frame on the Buffer
        End Using

        'Draw the Buffer on the user screen
    End Sub
End Class
```

OR

```
Public Class FpsEngine 'Exmaple Object
    Private Buffer As Bitmap
    Private g As Graphics
    Public Sub New()
        'initialize the object
        g = Graphics.FromImage(Buffer) 'Create the graphics object
    End Sub
    Public Sub DrawFrame() 'This fucntion will be called a lot of times and must be optimal
        'Draw the frame on the Buffer using the public Graphics object (g)

        'Draw the Buffer on the user screen
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note - the DrawFrame function is not running on the main GUI thread, thats why I am not drawing directly on the user screen, I am drawing all the frame on a buffer then after everything (the frame) is ready I am interrupting the main GUI thread am make a Fast Image to Screen Draw.

Comment: I would say that since you are copying the same bitmap to the screen each time, that it would be better to make your `Graphics` object a class level member like your second example.  No need for a new one each time.  I have no idea if you will be able to get an acceptable framerate this way, however.

Comment: Well in matter of fact, I can make 2 buffers and run on 2 threads for each buffer, doubling the framerate and lets say I want to get to 30 fps (I need to draw a frame in 33 milisec (it is possible), but the question is still what is better to use, or what is the right way to use the Graphics object. (personally I always try to avoid using public variables because of side effects (unwilling object mutation)).

Comment: In this case, it would be a private variable to the class.  I think you would incur some overhead newing up a new bitmap and calling the FromImage method.  Maybe it's negligible.  The only way to know for sure is to measure it.